# Dividing or subtracting : Normal PDF's? of independent random variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, arithmetic

There is clear rule how to multiply OR sum Normal PDF's i.e.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

$N_1(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1) + N_2(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2) = N(\mu_1+\mu_2,\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2)$

Is there similar formula for DIVISION and SUBTRACTION of normal PDFs ?

---

Here is the product :

$N_1(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1) * N_2(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2) = N((\sigma^2_1*\mu_1+\sigma^2_2*\mu_2) / (\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2), 1/ (1/\sigma^2_1)+ (1/\sigma^2_2))$

sorry dont know how to format those things

Comment: (1) you're not actually adding the *distributions* in your line of symbols there. You're showing the distribution that comes from adding  *random variables* -- and your formula only works when they're independent. (2) How are you doing the product?

Comment: The product of two normal random variables isn't normal. If each $\sigma$ is small relative to its $\mu$, it may sometimes be reasonable to approximate the product with a normal distribution. However, I don't think your parameters there can be correct.

Comment: I meant PDF product... sorry I'm not statistician and may be confusion the term.
The whole Baysian programming is build on Product and Sum of Normal-PDF's ... I was just wondering if there is similar formulas for Division and Substraction.

Comment: You want a product of the pdfs? But that's not consistent with your formula for the sum. You didn't add pdfs there, you added the random variables! Please edit so that your question is internally consistent.

Comment: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/10/29/product-of-normal-pdfs/

Comment: Take a look at the first part of your question, where you give a formula for the sum. Are you adding pdfs there? No! So why are you talking about a product of pdfs once you come to the product? Do you want to ask about operations on pdfs or do you want to ask about operations on random variables? Right now, you have one of each. Pick one, because right now your question is not internally consistent.

Comment: @Glen_b I've seen people use the notation for the distribution to refer to a random variable itself that follows that distribution. I've been guilty of doing this in the past, but that's probably what's going on here

Comment: @user1019129 adding the PDF is not the same as adding the random variable. The PDF $p$ is a function that describes the density of the random variable, so "$p_x(x) + p_y(y)$" is a function of $x$ and $y$ whose value is the sum of the densities of $x$ and $y$. $X + Y$ is a random variable that can be constructed by drawing a value $x$ randomly according to the distribution of $X$ and a value $y$ randomly according to the distribution of $Y$, and then adding the result. In general, $p_{x+y} \neq p_x + p_y$.

Comment: @user1019129 also, if by "Bayesian programming" you mean "programming Bayesian models," then I think you misunderstand what Bayesian modeling is.

Answer (score 7):

Since we don't seem to be getting the message across, here's the problem with your question:

[image]

(These examples are for $X_1\sim N(0,1/4)$ and $X_2\sim N(5/2, 9/4)$. In column B the random variables were assumed to be independent.)

You need to pick whether you're really asking about column A or column B. You're currently asking about A2 and B1. They're different kinds of things!

Edit: additional explanation --

Let $X_1\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$ and $X_2\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2)$. The density of $X_1$ is $f_1(x)$ and the density of $X_2$ is $f_2(x)$.

Then the sum of the two densities is $f_1(x)+f(2)(x)$. This is shown in image A1. (It is not a density, but if scaled to integrate to 1, corresponds to a finite mixture of normals.)

The product of the two densities is $f_1(x).f_2(x)$. This is shown in image A2. (It is not a density, but if scaled to integrate to 1, corresponds to a normal.)

[Since we're dealing only with operations the density functions, independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is irrelevant to the above.]

The density of the sum is the density of the sum $X_1+X_2$. The case for jointly normal $(X_1,X_2)$ is given in Dilip's answer. If they're independent, that gives the result in your question. They may of course not be jointly normal, but dependent in some other way, in which case the distribution of the sum will be different. The independent case is shown in image B1.

The density of the product is the density of the product $X_1\,X_2$. The general case is a little complicated, but some special cases are more well known. None of these are normal, but some cases may be approximately normal. For example if both $\sigma_i$s are small relative to $|\mu_i|$, and the variables are independent, you get a distribution that's approximately normal. The independent case for random variates from the two normals mentioned above is shown in image B2.

---

If you're interested in the difference and ratio of density functions (i.e. all column A-type calculations), here are examples using the two normal pdfs above above:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your patience.. I'm reading this : 
http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/05_Kalman_Filters.ipynb
and he is explaining multiplying and summing Gaussians. Search for "new_gaussian = measurement * old_gaussian" for the section.

Comment: I can see the differences in the graphs, but don't understand the meaning. Cant figure out what is juxtaposition between "X of densities" vs "density of X".

Comment: I'm thinking of them as having formulas for two curves, then you can multiply or sum them and get another curve.
This is probably where my "abstraction" go astray.

Comment: I'm probably talking about column A. But would like to understand the difference, if you can point me to a resource that compares them. thanks again

Comment: Can you post the code you used to generate the graphs.

Comment: Is the column A : PDF and column B: CDF ?

Comment: No, the second set of graphs are all based on pdfs. Check the titles, which state clearly what is graphed.

Answer (score 6):

- If $X$ and $Y$ are *jointly* normal random variables, then $$X\pm Y \sim N\big(\mu_X \pm \mu_Y, \operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{var}(Y)\pm 2\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)\big).$$
- If $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables, 
  then $\displaystyle \frac{X}{Y}$ (and also 
  $\displaystyle \frac YX$) has a standard Cauchy distribution.

Both of the above facts have been discussed numerous times on stats.SE

- Your assertion about the distribution of $XY$ is incorrect: $XY$ 
  *does not* enjoy a normal distribution.