# Distribution of product of samples from two Normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, nonlinear

## Hello!

I have two normally distributed random variables $M \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $V \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ having physical meaning as $M$ - mass and $V$ - volume.

I need to figure out the corresponding p.d.f of variable $D$ - density *(physical)* given by formula $D=\frac{M}{V}$ *(basic physical density formula)*. Combining those two densities seems wrong to me as they are of different physical dimensions and are connected by a nonlinear formula. So I tried sampling from both $M$ and $V$ distributions and then simply computing resulting density samples via the formula given above `density_samples = mass_samples / volume_samples` element-wise.

I was expecting the result to also be Gaussian Normal distribution, although the following pictures show its either skewed normal or some other distribution. I would like to model the density distribution $D$ as closely as possible in order to use it for estimation of components *(Generally, the Gaussians $M$ and $V$ may be Gaussian Mixture Models, ergo the $D$ would also be a mixture)*.

#### Question

What is the proper way in modeling such distribution that are transformed by a nonlinear operation as division? ($D=\frac{M}{V}$). Is there some rule on how Normal Distribution behaves after non-linear transformation? (e.g. it becomes skewed or something like that?)

## Figures

#### Normal Distribution of mass $M$

[image: Normal Distribution of mass]

#### Normal Distribution of volume $V$

[image: Normal Distribution of volume]

#### Unknown Distribution of density $D$

Looks like Skewed Normal Distribution
[image: Some Distribution of density]

Comment: This [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution) article on the distribution of ratios has the exact form of what you are looking for

Comment: [Is the ratio distribution of two normally distributed variables ever normal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162483/is-the-ratio-distribution-of-two-normally-distributed-variables-ever-normal?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I was not sure how to describe the problem properly so I did not find dupliactes.